# VPN Device name

Tags: azure, vpn, checkpoint, azure-vpn

I use microsoft azure virtual network with a VPN gateway, I want to connect to a checkpoint site to site VPN.

The other party asks what is my VPN device name. Which I dont have an answer to. Are they asking a brand name?

Azure portal says VPN type: route based. But it does not show a device name anywhere. How to solve this? thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The other party asks what is my VPN device name.

Azure VPN gateway does not provide VPN device name, you could give **your VPN gateway Public IP Address** to checkpoint manager.

More information about how to create site-to-site VPN between Azure and checkpoint please refer to this [link](https://carlos.mendible.com/2016/05/02/create-azure-site-site-vpn/).

Also, you could create site-to-to VPN by using Azure Portal, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal).